# Laravel country code validation with regex

Tags: regex, laravel

I want to validate for country code using regex. The country code should be like +567, that is a plus sign and 3 digits only.

I am doing like this

```
'country_code'      => 'regex:/^([+])d{1,3}/',
```

But its not working as expected. How can I achieve tis?

Comment: You missed `\` before `d` and should write `\d`.

Comment: Thank @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi for the response. I changed it to

 'regex:/^([+])\d{1,3}/'
But still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match 1 - 3 digits only preceded with a plus:

```
^\+\d{1,3}$
```

Note that you don't need the parenthesis for the capturing group, the d should be escaped with a backslash `\d` and you could add the anchor `$` to assert the end of the string.

To match exactly 3 digits, the `{1,3}` would become `{3}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJrFuZ/1)

```
'country_code'      => 'regex:/^\+\d{1,3}$/',
```

Comment: Thanks @bird, It's working as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `'country_code'  => 'regex:/([+])\d{1,3}/'`.

Comment: Thanks, @Kashyap, but it's accepting more than 3 characters and string as well. I want to restrict to numbers only.

Comment: Can you send me your test data?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this expression

```
'country_code'  => 'regex:/^([+])\d{3}$/'
```

which accept exactly 3 digits but if you want to accept 1-3 digits replace `{3}` with `{1,3}`

or you can use this expresion if you don't want to capture plus sign

```
'country_code'  => 'regex:/^\+\d{3}$/'
```